# Refresh SQL Server Credentials

Tags: vb.net

How can I refresh my connection strings without reloading/restarting my application? When I put correct credentials in the textbox through my.settings (app.config) it opens when I put incorrect credentials without restarting the app still opens but I should expect “cannot open database “mydb” requested by the login…” How can I do it in vb.net here’s my tested codes.

```
Try 
Using connection as New sqlClient.sqlConnection(constr)
Connection.open()
If connection.state=connectionstate.open then
Msgbox(“Online”)
Else
Msgbox(“Offline”)
End if
End using
Catch sqex as sqlclient.sqlconnection
Msgbox(sqex.message)
End Try
```

Connection String in Module1

```
Public constr As String = "Data source='" & My.Settings.myserver & "';
'    database='" & My.Settings.mydb & "'; 
'    uid='" & My.Settings.myuid & "'; 
'    password='" & My.Settings.mypwd & "'; 
'    connection timeout=0; 
'    Max Pool Size=32767; Pooling=True"

Where
Textbox1 = server
Textbox2 = db
Textbox3 = uid
Textbox4 = pwd
```

Comment: There is no textbox in your code example from which you construct the connection string passed to the `Connection` object.

Comment: Guessing constr is created somewhere up stream, perhaps app_start.  Simple thing is to have a function that builds and returns the connection string with the current credentials.  Keep the current credentials in memory (Security implications of course) and update as required

Comment: Please check connection string above.